# How to rewrite this NSAppleScript example into SBApplication or Native Cocoa codes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, applescript

For example, the `NSAppleScript` object is used like this.

```
NSString * st = @"tell application \"System Events\" to tell (process 1 where frontmost is true) \n"
            "click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 \n"
            "end tell";
[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:st]

[aps executeAndReturnError:nil]
```

It looks simple, but I need to create the string of applescript, which is a little clumsy. Is there a way to rewrite the codes by `SBApplication` or Cocoa APIs?

Comment: You asked a similar question a few days ago.  'Translate this code for me' is not something you should do here.  Especially, not twice...  -1

Comment: [Accessibility API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/Reference/reference.html), [tag:accessibility-api]